Why did Verna kill these other people?
In the 2023 series The Fall of the House of Usher,

 Verna is pretty clear that the price that she will take is the entire Usher family, and that anything else they do in the interim, is up to them; in particular, she says that they could choose to harm or help people with Fortunato Pharmaceuticals (although, realistically, she certainly knew what they would choose).

She even goes out of her way to ensure that some people who are not in the terms of the deal survive; she explicitly gets the waiters at Prospero's party to leave, and even Morella's "lucky" survival out of all the people at the party despite equally severe injuries seems likely to be a function of this.
However, in two cases, she ensures the deaths of people who are not from the Usher bloodline, and thus presumably not covered by the deal (unlike Lenore, say): almost all the people who attended Prospero's party, and Dr. Ruiz. Her responsibility for these events can easily be inferred from the way she used her basically limitless powers to arrange the precise sequence of events around the deaths of each member of the Usher family.
Why is this? Is it because she took the opportunity to kill them outside the terms of the deal because she thought they were deserving of death? (But would she really see "attending an orgy" as a capital crime, and wouldn't she see Ruiz's motivations and resolve to expose the Usher family as even positive?) Because she had to stop there from being any evidence to prevent the Ushers from being convicted of crimes before they died, per the terms of the deal? (But wasn't that only necessary because of the specific flashy ways she chose to kill them?) Because they in fact had all actually made deals with her before, and she contrived things to be able to kill multiple birds with one stone, as it were?

It's been a while since I watched, but I thought it was all set-up to drive the family mad/insane, create division, suspicious etc.
